# CS-CART Themeing

Tags: themes, smarty, cs-cart

I have been looking into using CS-CART as a shopping cart and started looking through the themes and it appears to me the only way to build a theme is to extend a default theme and use the theme editor and visual designer to construct themes. Is this the only way or is there a way to code custom themes without being limited to designing in the administration section?

Answer (score 1):

The theme editor is intended to be used as a customization tool for the site administrator, not for the theme developer.

A theme may provide configuration for the theme editor - what colors can be changed, etc.

For the deep customization of how the site looks you can create you own theme with your own CSS code.

Check out this guide on how to create your custom theme - http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.3.x/designer_guide/theme_tutorial/index.html

Also there is an official Bootstrap 3 theme for CS-Cart which can be easily customized - https://github.com/cscart/cscart-boilerplate#the-cs-cart-boilerplate-theme

Answer (score 0):

You are not limited, you have all the tools that you need to develop as you desire, the responsive theme is the base because this theme was tested enough so far and have good feedback and for somebody to start from scratch will take to much time and until you finish CS-Cart will do a big change and you will need to do another work ;)

Please check https://www.ambientlounge.ie and let me know if you find any limitations here :D

Comment: That is a great looking website. I do not see any limitations but I guess was looking at the best way to do a custom design rather than be limited by the editor because that seemed to be all the tutorials showed as the process.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy modift cs-cart theme, cs-cart theme base on bootstrap and and smarty engine, firt you need looking for "index.tpl", "common/script.tpl", "common/style.tpl", "view/block_manager/render/grid.tpl || container.tpl || block.tpl || location.tpl. and you will understand cs-cart theme structure

You need to know smarty engine syntax here http://www.smarty.net/documentation

and cs-cart developer doc here http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.3.x/#designer-guide

Comment: This is great information and a great start. I will let you know how it works out.

Comment: My question still remains though is if you can design in the files rather than using the editor?

Comment: I recommended using editor, using html block or smarty block, dont modift template core file, so easy to update the template fo future